# PHP best way to output certain data to text?

Tags: php, html, fwrite, output-buffering

Ok, so I have a form that takes a username and a code. This is then passed to php for processing. I am not super php saavy, so I want to be able to take a specific portion of the out put and write it to a text file, this form would be used over and over, and I want the text to be appended to the file. As you can see from the output I'm looking to capture, it's basically writing to some code that will be used for usernames in a css. So here is what I have...

1. The HTML Form

```
<html><body>
<h4>Codes Form</h4>
<form action="codes.php" method="post"> 
Username: <input name="Username" type="text" />
Usercode: <input name="Usercode" type="text" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Post It!" />
</form>
</body></html>
```

1. The PHP

```
--><html><body>
<?php
$Usercode = $_POST['Usercode'];
$Username = $_POST['Username'];

echo "You have recorded the following in our system ". $Username . " " . $Usercode . ".<br />";
echo "Thanks for contributing!";

echo .author[href$="/$Username"]:after {
echo content: "($Usercode)"
echo }

?>
</body></html>
```

All that I would like to be written to the text file would be this portion..

```
--> .author[href$="/$Username"]:after {
 content: "($Usercode)"
 }
```

Basically, the text file would have line after line of that exact same code, but with different usernames and usercodes. Hopefully, the variable $Usercode and $Username can also be captured and written into the output in the manner that I have it written. I'm just baffled by output buffering in php and clean and flush etc, and fwrite doesn't seem to be able to write without wiping a file clean each time it writes to it. I may be wrong of course. Anyone care to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$output = "--> .author[href=$Username]:after { \n"
       ."content: ($Usercode)\n"
       ."}";
$fp = fopen($file, 'a');
fwrite($fp, $output);
fwrite($fp, "\n");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

The flag `a` will open already a text file and place the pointer to the end of file, so this will not overwrite your already file, more information in [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Comment: Wow, that was fast. I'll be able to throw it on my server later this evening to see if I'm settled. Quick addendum, Again forgive me because my PHP knowledge is very limited and it's only somewhat readable due to experiencing in other languages and most of those are high level "easy peasy" scripting languages. In the $fp = fopen($file, 'a'); line.. is $file a variable that I need to set somewhere to define the file and path to write to? or can it be replaced with the path "on the fly" IE: ($/path/to/file.txt/, 'a'); Be gentle lol

Comment: And I answered that one myself its the file in dir. Thanks again SIFE.

Comment: Ok, this nearly works perfectly. My problem is when I try to tell $output to write the following, it fails. Likely due to the usage of $ and " " in the output. However, without it, it's kind of useless. The output has to be in this format >>    .author[href$="/$Username"]:after {
    content: "($Usercode)"
    }

Comment: Arrgh, and again I figured it out. Sorry to spam up things here. Today I learned how to escape special characters in php with a ridiculous amount of backslashes lol. Thanks again SIFE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND); where $file is the path of the file you are writing to, data is the whatever value you are writing to the file. This assumes you are using php5. If not, you will have to create a handle with fopen, write to the file with fwrite and end with fclose to close the file pointed to in your fopen handle.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm afraid I don't run PHP5 but I'm glad you mentioned this as I would have learned the hard way haha. I believe the second answer falls in line with your second recommendation for non PHP5 environments. I'll give that one a shot later and cross my finger :D Love this community!